# Magento: how to obtain transaction response

Tags: magento

Does anyone know how to get the following array, or data similar to it, for a given order in Magento? More specifically, I'm interested in the `avsaddr`, `avszip`, and `cvv2match`.

```
Array 
( 
    [result] => 0 
    [pnref] => xxxx
    [respmsg] => Approved 
    [authcode] => 120632 
    [avsaddr] => N 
    [avszip] => Y 
    [cvv2match] => N 
    [hostcode] => 00 
    [procavs] => Z 
    [proccvv2] => N 
    [iavs] => N 
    [request_id] => xxx
    [result_code] => 0 
)
```

I'm using Payflow Pro (not Payflow Link) and we have AVS and CVV verifications enabled. They are being checked and flagged on Paypal's end.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get it in the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment` model.  Looking at the `sales_flat_order_payment` table, I see `cc_avs_status`, which should give some information on the AVS response for the payment.

From the test payment data I'm looking at, that value is not populated, so it may vary based on what payment method you are using, whether it's storing that information.

`Mage_Authorizenet_Model_Directpost` does seem to set that value, judging by the `_fillPaymentByResponse()` method.

Comment: `cc_avs_status` is always empty for our orders with Payflow PRO. After looking at some codes in `/Mage/.../Paypal/Api`, it looks like there are columns named 'cvv2_check_result` and `avs_result` somewhere.. I haven't been able to locate them, though. Is there a way to find certain columns by their names in the Magento DB?

Comment: Actually, I just found it in this table: `sales_flat_order_payment`. But our test orders got deleted, so I'll have to check again later..